# vba powerpoint populating an array from excel range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, powerpoint

I´m trying to set a array with data from a MS Excel range. 
My VBA Macro replaces the text from an array with text from another array. 
It works fine with arrays, but now I´m trying to fill these arrays with data from a Excel file. I´m using range and I´ve tried thousands of ways of making  itwork, unsuccessfuly.  I´m not a VBA coder, so maybe I´m missing some basic concepts.... :|

Heres the code. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
Sub ReplacePT2ES()

    Dim oSld As Slide
    Dim oShp As Shape
    Dim oTxtRng As TextRange
    Dim oTmpRng As TextRange
    Dim strWhatReplace As String, strReplaceText As String
    Dim x As Long


    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim rng As range


    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\DOCS\DiccionarioPT2ES.xlsx")
    xlBook.Application.Visible = False
    xlBook.Application.WindowState = xlMinimized


    Dim findList As Variant
    Dim replaceList As Variant

    Set findList = range("A1:A3").Value

    Set replaceList = range("B1:B3").Value
    '-- works fine with array
    'findList = Array("falha", "lei", "projeto", "falhas", "leis", "projetos", "falham", "os", "as", "gestor")
    'replaceList = Array("falla", "ley", "proyecto", "fallas", "leyes", "proyectos", "fallan", "los", "las", "gerente")

    'MsgBox "Iniciando!"

    For x = findList.Count To replaceList.Count
        ' go during each slides
        For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
             ' go during each shapes and textRanges
            For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
                 ' replace in TextFrame
                'If oShp.HasTextFrame And UBound(findList) And UBound(replaceList) > 0 Then
                 If oShp.HasTextFrame Then

                    Set oTxtRng = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                    Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=findList(x), Replacewhat:=replaceList(x), WholeWords:=True)

                    Do While Not oTmpRng Is Nothing

                        Set oTxtRng = oTxtRng.Characters(oTmpRng.Start + oTmpRng.Length, oTxtRng.Length)
                        Set oTmpRng = oTxtRng.Replace(FindWhat:=findList(x), Replacewhat:=replaceList(x), WholeWords:=True)
                    Loop
                 End If
            Next oShp
        Next oSld
    Next x

 xlBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
 Set xlApp = Nothing
 Set xlBook = Nothing
 'MsgBox "Listo!"


End Sub
```

Comment: If you open your locals window and step through the macro with F8, when you get to the line fa x = ... Inspect findlist and replacelist. Do they hold the values from your excel sheet like you expect them to?

Comment: add full path to the range, specify both workbook ad worksheet like `wb.ws.Range("A1:A3")` , where `wb` and `ws` are the variable names which you have set the wanted workbook and worksheet objects to. in your code you already have set `xlBook` to the wanted workbook, so you're missing two statements: the declaration of a Worksheet object variable (`dim ws as Worksheet`) and that variable initialization (`set ws = xlBook.Worksheets("putYourActualSheetName")`)

Comment: Thanks Rodger, the list actualy yes, it show the content of the excel. The problem, I think, is about the kind of variables. When it´s array it works fine, when I try to assing the values from the Range datatype, is when it doesnt work. Thats why my question, so far,  is: how to put the data range values into the array.

Answer (score 1):

Finaly I found a solution: stop using Array and swith to Dictionary. 
Here the code wich worked:

```
Set findList = range("A1:A10")
Dim MyDictionary As Object
Set MyDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With MyDictionary
    For Each RefElem In findList
        If Not .Exists(RefElem) And Not IsEmpty(RefElem) Then
            .Add RefElem.Value, RefElem.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End If
    Next RefElem
End With
```

Moral of the history: use the right datatype for the job ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up your code significantly by:

1. Looping through a variant array rather than a range
2. Splitting your IF test into two parts (VBA doesn't shortcircuit so will evaluate both parts of an `AND` even if the first part is False).

*code*

```
Sub Recut()
Dim X
Dim MyDictionary As Object
Dim lngRow As Long
Set MyDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

X = Range("A1:B10").Value2
With MyDictionary
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X)
    If Len(X(lngRow, 1)) > 0 Then
        If Not .Exists(X(lngRow, 1)) Then .Add X(lngRow, 1), X(lngRow, 2)
    End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```